# How to edit the attribute tabel of a shapefile when the enable editing is greyed out?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am not really confident with QGIS.

I am looking for at way to  edit the attribute table of a shapefile, but the enable editing button is greyed out.

How do i fix it?

My end goal is to add a column to the file I have (which is a world map), so I can color code the world's nations according to their CO2e emissions.

I use QGIS 3.0.1.

Here's a photo of the attribute table:

[image]

And a photo of what it looks like without coloring the different attributes:

[image]

Also, here is the actual file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uftFMIc8AVLBWcyV_I5ryn0psw1Y80oM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you try looking at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79957/how-to-fix-greyed-out-edit-button?rq=1

Comment: you should give some more information about the origin of your shapefile ...

Comment: have you selected the layer in layers panel?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for responding. Yes, I did select the layer in layers panel. I have attacked a photo of the attribute table if that helps.

Comment: If you can't edit shapefile, maybe is located in a disk unwritable or you don't have necessary permissions. You can go to layer panel, right-click, save as and save layer in another place

Comment: Hey, thanks for pitching in. The file is located in a standard folder on my HDD.

Comment: I was able to edit the layer without problems. The issue is located in your machine

Comment: Hey Aldo, thanks a lot. Im not sure why, but I had the file in a G.drive folder and when i moved in onto my actual HDD it became editable! Thanks for pinpointing the issue

Comment: @AndreSilva You're right - my editing workflow lapsed - the asker should now ping me and/or flag to get this question reviewed if they change their mind about it being solved and decide to revise it.